# Visual studio TypeScript error "Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided."

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

When trying to compile and export a typescript module I get this error. 
I have read a few articles but none fix my problem, I am using VS2015 Exterprise, 
Thanks

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue those whosoever is voting down the question should answer the question at-least.

Comment: I didn't get any proper solution to this issue and it seems very strange for for now I did resolve in other way by choosing template "HTML Application with TypeScript" while creating New Project in visual studio with Typescript project template. (New Project > TypeScript > HTML Application with TypeScript).

Comment: Thanks, I am using the MVC asp template. so this would not be a solution for me,

Answer (score 2):

> Visual studio TypeScript error “Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided.”

Right click the project and select "properties". Click on the TypeScript page in the project properties and then select your module (I personally recommend commonjs with webpack for frontend/browser or as is for nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem a while ago myself and probably your visual studio project file is messed up. This can either be because of a Visual Studio bug or because you have used a messed up project file.

I described what fixed it for me in [this post](http://www.mvdcorput.nl/2016/04/vs2015-typescript-cannot-compile-modules-unless-module-flag-provided-build-error/).